# Jquery Validation Unvalidated form submit button able to be clicked (With Fiddle)

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation

I have a Jquery form with a validation script on the URL, it correctly validates and invalidates the URL. However, when it invalidates the URL, it still allows the form button to be clicked, but not submitted.

This causes the hidden loading image to show even though the form is no being submitted.

Here is a fiddle with the loader and script
http://jsfiddle.net/mikeef74/gzSDH/16/

```
var submit_hit = false;

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#iframe1').on('load', function () {
        $('#loader1').hide();
        if (submit_hit) {
            $('#form_container').hide();
            $('#mydivhide1, #mydivhide2').show();
            $('body').css("background-image", "url(images/previewbg7.jpg)");
            $('body').css("overflow-y", "auto");
        }
    }
});

$("#form_710370").validate();
$('#form_710370').submit(function (e) {
    $('#loader1').show();
        submit_hit = true;
        return true;
    });
});
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @JonKoops I don't know why the loader animation is triggering before the form is submitted. The validation script stops the form from being submitted if it is not validated when the submit is clicked, but it still triggers the loading animation. I guess I should just block the submit before its validated, but I thought I could do it this way.

Comment: What is your support target?

Comment: @JonKoops sorry I am new to Jquery, I really don't know what that means

Comment: Not related to jQuery. I just want to know which browsers & versions you intend to support on this project.

Comment: @JonKoops IE8-10, Safari, FireFox, Chrome. Don't care about IE6-7 anymore, latest stats show less than 1% use it. I figure they are use to sites not working...lol

Comment: Okay, I was gonna suggest using the url input but that's not supported under IE10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The submit event will trigger whenever you attempt to submit. You've defined a submit event handler tied to the form which is why the image is showing.

Seems you want to trigger the loader image on a conditional submit so you'll need to use the validation's `submitHandler`. Now the inner function will only trigger when the form is valid -- the loader image will display and the form will be explicitly submitted.

```
$("#form_710370").validate({
    submitHandler: function(form) {
        $("#loader1").show();
        submit_hit = true;
        form.submit();
    }
});

// remove this
//$('#form_710370').submit(function (e) { ... }
```

http://jqueryvalidation.org/documentation/

Comment: That fixes the loading image, but the `if (submit_hit) {` events don't work with that change to the code.

Comment: add submit_hit = true in the submitHandler

Answer (score 0):

**This is way validate a form in jquery:**

```
 $(function() {
            $("#form_710370").validate({
                rules: {
                          //
                       },
                messages: {
                       //
                       },
        submitHandler: function(form) {
                    form.submit();
                }
            });
        });
```